# How to get print to format its output in python?

Tags: python, printing

`print(reprt('Hello\nHello'))` will print `b'Hello\nHello'` and I would like it to print

```
Hello
Hello
```

instead. The reason for this is that some functions such as `subprocess.check_output` send a repr output.

```
params = r'"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -c ' + r"""'ls "C:\Users"'""" 

print(subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True))
```

Comment: You are on the wrong track. 1) why invoke bash explicitly, if you want a shell, just use shell=True. 2) why use a shell? You can invoke 'ls' directly. 3) Why use ls? you can use os.listdir() to list files in a directory.  4) No commands "send repr output", you are confused about what you are seeing.  Show the actual command you are running, and the actual output you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

then dont use repr just use

```
print("hello\nhello")
```

demo

tracing.py

```
print("hello\nhello")
```

otherscript.py

```
import subprocess

print subprocess.check_output('python tracing.py')
```

output

```
hello
hello
```

Comment: I'll quote myself : "The reason for this is that some functions such as subprocess.check_output send a repr output."

Comment: @Wicelo can you give example of such condition here using check_output

Comment: `params = r'"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" --login -c ' + r"""'ls "C:\Users"'"""

print(subprocess.check_output(params, shell=True))`

Answer (score -2):

you could try this:

```
>>> eval(repr("Hello"))
'Hello'
```